# rvest html_element doesn't allow me to extract text (<span) : character 0 or Na

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

As a beginner in web scrapping, I've been trying for 1 week to extract information from the "Performance environnementales" et "Caractéristiques techniques" tables on the https://carto.viaseva.org/public/viaseva/building/#/panel/building/b/building_id/3514C web page.

I've tried three different methods, but none of them works.

with r selenium :

```r
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

rd <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
remDr <- rD [["client"]]
```

produced the following error:

```r
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567 after 2221 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome") : Could not determine server status.
```

with rvest's `html_node()` :

```r
p <-read_html("https://carto.viaseva.org/public/viaseva/building/#/panel/building/b/building_id/3514C")
viaseva <-html_node(p,"span [class = 'text-right']") %>%
  html_text()
```

which produces the following result

```r
viaseva : chr Na
```

The same happens when I use the following selector `"div#list-container > ul > li" instead of span [class = 'text-right'`.  I also tried `html_element()`

```r
p <-read_html("https://carto.viaseva.org/public/viaseva/building/#/panel/building/b/building_id/3514C")
elementviaseva <- html_elements(p, css = ".text-right")
textviaseva <- html_text(elementviaseva, trim = TRUE)
```

and got the following result:

```r
head (textviaseva)
character (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you want does not exist at the url you type into your address bar in the browser. This url sends some html to your browser that contains javascript code. The browser runs the javascript code, which then fetches the data from the url https://carto.viaseva.org/anonymous/buildings/viaseva/3514C/view in the form of a json file.

When you use `rvest`, the html is delivered to your R session as text, so the javascript isn't run, and the data isn't fetched.

Instead of trying to scrape from html elements, you can just read the json and parse it to get the information you want. Here's a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(httr)

d <- GET('https://carto.viaseva.org/anonymous/buildings/viaseva/3514C/view') |>
       content('parsed')

performance <- d |>
  getElement('info') |>
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(measure = x$display_name,
                                value = as.character(x$value))) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()


caracteristics <- d |>
  getElement('caracteristics_info') |>
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(measure = x$display_name,
                                value = as.character(x$value))) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

We now have our two tables in data frames in our R session:

```r
performance
#>                               measure value
#> 1 Livraisons totales de chaleur (MWh) 797.1
#> 2                    Taux d’EnR&R (%)  0.49
#> 3        Emissions de CO2 (g CO2/kWh)   152
#> 4               Equivalents Logements    70
#> 5         Année de création du réseau  2017
caracteristics
#>                                  measure value
#> 1                   Longueur réseau (km)   0.6
#> 2                    Points de livraison     8
#> 3      % Fluide caloporteur - Eau chaude   100
#> 4 % Fluide caloporteur - Eau surchauffée     0
#> 5          % Fluide caloporteur - Vapeur     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, how can know its jsonfile and not html file?

Comment: @mfrere the fact that the elements you can find with the selector gadget are not found when scraping the html with rvest suggests that the web page is created _dynamically_.  If this happens, press F12 in your browser to open the developer pane and click on the console tab. This will allow you to see what other data the web page is downloading. If one or more of these is json, it's likely that your data is in one of these. Just copy the url from the console and use it in R.